# Google Play Console - Managed Google Play (B2B) - Closed Tracks not distributing

Tags: android, google-play-console, mdm, emm

We have an app only available in the Managed Google Play Store to a single customer, an external Organization, as well as our own Organization; we've done this by going to the Advanced Settings and turning on "Managed Google Play" and then adding the Organization IDs. We've promoted the app to Production and now this works as expected and the app is available in the Managed Google Play Store for us and for our customer, the external Organization.

> [image: Managed Google Play Advanced Settings]

We are trying to now use a Closed Track. We've uploaded the new version of the APK to the Google Play Console and created a Closed Track release. The APK has a higher version code than the APK in Production. We've added our Organization ID to the APK in the Closed Track as well as the Organization ID of our customer. So we've now added these two Organization IDs in two places; once in the Advanced Settings of the app as a whole, and once in the Closed Track.

> [image: Closed track distribution to organization]

We've ensured that our individual tester account has enrolled into the testing, and the url indicates "You are a tester".

> [image: You are a tester]

However when the tester clicks the link "download it on Google Play." the tester gets the error message "requested URL was not found".

> [image: Requested URL not found]

Our problem is that the APK in the Closed Track is never distributed, neither to our internal Organization nor to our customer. We've waited hours, days and now more than a week and nothing has changed.

Comment: This continues to be a problem.